# Flutter app not working properly in release version

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using Firebase in my project to get the data. Problem is when I run debug version app works fine and show the fetched data but when I create a release version of it and then open my application It's shows blank screen. It is strange and I am not getting why this happening. To understand the issue I have given the two videos of it and also the project repository link, and the problem I am facing in the Book_Screen.dart.

Project Link: https://github.com/jaydip-pawar/Hindi-Audio-Bible

`In Debug Version:`

[image]

`In Release Version:`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to catch problem in release mode. But you can try to open "Uncaught Exception" from the debug panel and if some error occurs, try to fix them.

If you can't solve  the problem, you can comment widgets one by one. In this way, you can look for the specific lines of code that  causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using playstore inbuilt keystore, add those sha1 from playstore to firebase app setting.